# How does one create receive addresses for a wallet programatically?

Tags: wallet

We wish to generate large numbers of receive addresses for a single wallet. These addresses will let us identify who is sending us Cardano, or other native assets. Can someone explain how one goes about generating such addresses?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://github.com/uniVocity/cardano-tutorials/blob/master/cardano-addresses.md

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multi address wallets are usually called Hierarchically Deterministic (HD) wallets and are defined by the [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) standard.

In Cardano, we do extend BIP44 in [CIP1852](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-1852/CIP-1852.md) by adding staking key capabilities, but this is not your use case.

To derive wallet addresses for a single wallet, it is easiest to use an existing library that can do this for you, as for example the [cardano-seralization-lib](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib) by Emurgo.

Have a look at [their documentation](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-serialization-lib/en/latest/getting-started/generating-keys.html), but this easy snippet you will show you how to derivate the 10th address of your wallet:

```
function harden(num: number): number {
  return 0x80000000 + num;
}


const rootKey = CardanoWasm.BIP32PrivateKey.from_bech32("xprv17qx9vxm6060qjn5fgazfue9nwyf448w7upk60c3epln82vumg9r9kxzsud9uv5rfscxp382j2aku254zj3qfx9fx39t6hjwtmwq85uunsd8x0st3j66lzf5yn30hwq5n75zeuplepx8vxc502txx09ygjgx06n0p");
const accountKey = rootKey
  .derive(harden(1852)) // purpose
  .derive(harden(1815)) // coin type
  .derive(harden(0)); // account #0

const utxoPubKey = accountKey
  .derive(0) // external
  .derive(9) // <- here is the index of your address, cycle thought this number to generate more of it
  .to_public();
```